# Excel VBA how to concatenate

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I need to concatenate a already existing code in vba so that the output it

"Rank", "-", Then the data that this formula finds

Here is the original code, it finds the data and puts it a data table un-concatenated.

```
For innerLoop = 0 To addRowOffset - 1
      Range("F" & maxRows + 1 - innerLoop).Value = _
       Sheets("Template").Range("B" & (6 + periodP * 2 + periodQ * 3 + innerLoop)).Value
Next innerLoop
```

here Is my failed  attempt at trying to concatenate it.

```
For innerLoop = 0 To addRowOffset - 1
      Range("F" & maxRows + 1 - innerLoop).Value = _
      Concatenate("Rank", "-", Sheets("Template").Range("B" & (6 + periodP * 2 + periodQ * 3 + innerLoop)).Value)
Next innerLoop
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just use &. "Rank-" & Sheets("Template").Range("B" & (6 + periodP * 2 + periodQ * 3 + innerLoop)).Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `&` to concatenate. And since you have two hard coded strings in a row, they can be combined into one.

```
For innerLoop = 0 To addRowOffset - 1
      Range("F" & maxRows + 1 - innerLoop).Value = _
      "Rank-" & Sheets("Template").Range("B" & (6 + periodP * 2 + periodQ * 3 + innerLoop)).Value
Next innerLoop
```